# Remove 1 second delay on countdown displaying

Tags: countdown

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/3kb337bt/

```
<span>Hurry, Sale Ends In: </span><div id="countdown"></div>
```

When the page loads the timer doesn't display right away. How can I remove the 1-2 second delay and make it display immediately?

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your `showRemaining()` function not being called on page load. It will take the specified delay (1000 in this case) until it gets called the first time. You can stop this by changing the delay since the countdown isn't affected by it.